# How find a process which removed/moved a given file in Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems

Suppose I have some files removed (or probably moved or renamed) in a Windows machine. Now I would like to find out what process removes/moves them. How can I do it?

Comment: To catch it while it's happening, you could use [procmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you need this in code, the only option is to have a filesystem filter driver intercept the requests and capture the information you need. Our CallbackFilter product lets one do this in user-mode (the driver is included).

Other options (not in code) are enable audit on the files in question and use ProcMon tool (Process Monitor by Sysinternals) to monitor the files.